# How do I create a shortcut to a folder using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do I create a shortcut to an existing folder in Windows Explorer?

In OS X, I would select the folder, then use Finder's `Make Alias` command (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most ideal solution, but if you have a keyboard with a [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) to open the context menu, you could select the folder and then press the context menu key to bring up the menu and then use the mnemonic for "Create shortcut" ('s' on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can do by left click the folder with the mouse and hold down the butten then move it where you want to place the folder. Before you release the mouse button hold the alt button on the keybord down and you will create a shortcut (lnk).